# How to use recursion with square?

Tags: python, class, recursion, tkinter

I have a question how can you recursively draw a rectangle with the use of fractional coordinates? I have been trying to make the squares/rectangles get smaller by 10% each time until it either takes up the entire canvas(meaning it cannot go beyond the width and height of the board or it just get's to 0 meaning it won't draw anything or it's so small you won't see the final square). Or maybe is there another way that I can go about drawing squares in a recursive way that keeps decreasing by a certain percent?

I have this so far but I can't seem to think of who to get it to continue to recurse until it can no longer do it.

```
import tkinter

class draw_squares:
    def __init__(self, squares: [(float, float, float, float)]):
        self.squares = squares

        self.root_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self.root_window,
                                     width = 500, height = 500,
                                     background = 'blue')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column = 0, padx=0, pady = 0,
                         sticky = tkinter.E + tkinter.W + tkinter.S + tkinter.N)

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._resized)

        self.root_window.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.root_window.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

    def start(self):
        self.root_window.mainloop()

    def _resized(self, event: tkinter.Event):
        self.draw_squares_recursively()

    def draw_squares_recursively(self):
        self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)

        for x, y, x2, y2 in self.squares:
            if x != 0.5 and y != 0.5 and x2 != 0.5 and y2 != 0.5:
                self._draw_square(self._draw_square(x-.1,y-.1,x2+.1,y2+.1))

    def _draw_square(self, x: float, y:float, x2:float, y2:float):
        width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        height = self.canvas.winfo_height()

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            x * width, y * height,
            x2 * width, y2 *height, outline = 'grey')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    squares = [(0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1), (0.8,0.8,0.2,0.2), (0.7,0.7,0.3,0.3),
               (0.6,0.6,0.4,0.4), (0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)]

    app = draw_squares(squares)
    app.start()
```

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using floating point numbers, so (not) equal is not a good idea http://www.lahey.com/float.htm draw_squares_recursively() can call itself until the limit is reached.  You can work out the arithmetic to get the sizes and locations you want.

```
class DrawSquares:
    def __init__(self, square):
##        self.squares = squares

        self.root_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self.root_window,
                                 width = 500, height = 500,
                                 background = 'blue')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column = 0, padx=0, pady = 0,
                     sticky = "nsew")

##        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._resized)

        self.root_window.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.root_window.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.draw_squares_recursively(square)
        self.root_window.mainloop()


    def draw_squares_recursively(self, square):
        ##self.canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)

        for value in square:
            if value < 0.05 or value > 100:
                return

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(square[0], square[1],
                                     square[2], square[3],
                                     outline = 'grey', width=2)
        square[2] += 20
        square[3] += 20
        self.draw_squares_recursively(square)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    squares = [0.9, 0.9, 10.1, 10.1]
    app = DrawSquares(squares)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying but I did have a few questions to ask? Why not have a start def in the class? Also I am a bit confused about what square[2] or square[3] += 20 do and was hoping you could elaborate on that. Also how would I do it where I could center the squares so instead of the squares starting out from the side it'll just start drawing like "[ [ [ [ ] ] ] ]" . So one square has a square 10% smaller than it inside of it and that square has another square 10% smaller than it inside of it? Also what if I want the squares to resize with the board? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: A tutorial on python and lists http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html

Comment: Thank you I got it! I appreciate the help :)